# How to kill existing port

Tags: node.js

My code is:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();

var logger = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url);
    next();
};
var helloWorld = function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World');
};
app.use(logger);
app.use(helloWorld);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

I have tried to run it again. Then I got an error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

As I understand I have to kill the port 3000.
Am I right? How to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you on? Linux?

Comment: When you ask a question here and people immediately respond with a clarifying question back to you - you SHOULD be here to respond back to them at least checking back several times in the first 30 minutes after you post.  If you can't do that, then wait to post until you can.  This site doesn't work very well if you post and then disappear - this site is much more interactive than other sites.  In fact, you're likely to get downvoted for being non-responsive to basic questions that come right after you post.

Comment: It is Mac operating system

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see your comment:(

Answer (score 2):

If you are on mac, then run  this command to find the PID of the process running on port 3000

```
lsof -i :3000
```

if you are on unix/linux, use this command to find the PID

```
netstat -anlp | grep 3000
```

Once you have the PID, run the kill command to kill it

```
kill -9 <PID from above command>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!